# Is the space between galaxies that are close to each other contracting?

Tags: general-relativity, universe, space-expansion, redshift

The Milky Way and Andromeda are moving towards each other as indicated by blueshift.

Are they just moving towards each other through space or the space between them contracting?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows [insufficient prior research](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/84967).

Comment: Space is expanding everywhere, even in your living room, but the excess of space is leaking out through the walls.

Comment: They are just moving. Space is expanding between them, but it is negligible comparing to their movement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the space between the Milky Way and Andromeda isn't expanding, but neither is it contracting. The two galaxies are moving towards each other.

When we talk about space expanding this is in the context of a solution to the Einstein equations called the [FLRW metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric). However this metric is a solution only for the special case of an isotropic and homogeneous distribution of matter. On a very large scale, i.e. larger than the size of [superclusters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercluster), observations suggest that the distribution of matter is homogeneous and therefore on this scale the FLRW metric is a good approximation to the geometry of the universe. However on smaller scales the universe is not homogeneous and the geometry is not FLRW.

Specifically when we have any gravitationally bound structure the spacetime geometry within that structure will not be FLRW. This applies to all scales from the moons of Pluto up to galaxy superclusters. The Milky Way and Andromeda are part of the gravitationally bound object called [the Local Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Group), along with the Triangulum galaxy and numerous smaller galaxies, so the FLRW metric does not apply within this group.

Comment: I understand that the universe on large scale is described by FLRW metric and is expanding.  But why doesn’t space between small bound structure like the Milky Way and Andromeda contract since the local scale gravity is strong enough to overcome expansion.

Comment: @Forge the issue is quite subtle. Space doesn't expand because space is not a thing, just a mathematical construction. The phrase *space is expanding* really means *the coordinate system in which the geometry is most simply written is expanding*. It's the *coordinate system* that is expanding not *space*. To fully explain all this would be a long answer. It's possible a question on this subject already exists. I'll have a look.

Comment: @Forge I'm currently [in the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) if you want to discuss it.

Answer (score 1):

They are moving towards each other through space. the space between them is actually expanding.

Comment: "the space between them is actually expanding" It is not, see John Rennie's excellent answer.